# Regular Expression for the given DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

[image]

Hi, what should be the regular expression for this language ? My guess was

r = (a
∗
a(a + b)
∗
(a + b) + (a
∗
b + c))(a + b
∗
)
∗

But the arrow from C to B is making it tough . If it was B to C then my answer would have bee correct.

Comment: Don't guess. Make a conjecture and prove it.

Comment: Once you get to the non-final state $B$ you will never leave, so think about whether you can eliminate $B$ from your automaton.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the alphabet of your DFA is $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$ it doesn't meet the standard definition of the transition function.

$M = \{Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F\}$

$\delta: Q\times \Sigma \rightarrow Q $

If you have a valid DFA then I suggest to use a proved algorithm(like State Removal Method for example) to transform it into a regular expression.